# How to get Inno Setup to install different programs running as different users?

Tags: go, windows-services, inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup to deploy a Windows 10 app in two parts. Written in Go...

service.exe is a Windows Service that needs to run as the system with elevated privilidges. It manipulates the network config.

settings.exe is a systray icon and settings GUI that communicates with the service via RPC. This needs to run under the user's account.

How can I get Inno Setup to deploy them so they run under the correct accounts?

In order to install the service, the install needs to run elevated. But if I do that, it installs the GUI to also use the system account. And I need to create the registry key to automatically start settings.exe after login.

What am I missing?

Comment: Installers (Inno Setup based or not) are usually executed as admin. There is nothing wrong there. I just cannot understand what you meant by "But if I do that, it installs the GUI to also use the system account". Even if an app is installed by an admin, it can be launched by non-admin users.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Thanks. See below.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out... The problem I had was permissions on the config files. i.e. The service started before the GUI and the service was running as System. So, the config file was owned by System and the current user did not have access. And the service can't fix it as it doesn't know who the user will be.

To fix this, I ran the GUI first just to create the config file as the current user. Now it has the current owner as Full Control in the ACL. And the System can still access it.

So... in Inno Setup...

```
[Run]
WorkingDir: "{app}"; Filename: "{app}\settings.exe"; Parameters: "install"; StatusMsg: "Installing with user permission"; Flags: runasoriginaluser runhidden 
WorkingDir: "{app}"; Filename: "{app}\service.exe"; Parameters: "install"; StatusMsg: "Installing with elevated permission"; Flags: runascurrentuser runhidden 
WorkingDir: "{app}"; Filename: "{app}\settings.exe"; Parameters: "open"; StatusMsg: "Starting settings."; Flags: nowait runasoriginaluser
```

I also found it easier to use the EXEs (not Inno Setup) to do configuration things like creating the registry entries for startup etc...

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if I am on the same wavelength but many of us install default files / registry in the common folders, hives. Then when the user starts the app it is our app that decides if it wants to copy these defaults across for the user. Like you say, the app (exe) does it at start up.